# What to use with Ember for serving the app? EAK/Yeoman/Etc?

Tags: ember.js

I'm confused on what I should use with Ember.

Should I use ember-app-kit? Should I use ember-rails? Should I use yeoman?

Which one of these is the recommended package management system to run an Ember app?

Comment: You should consider using someone elses API while you learn how to use something like Ember...

Comment: Yeah that's my point, even with such a thing, which do I use to keep the server running? There's several solutions. EAK, Yeoman... ember-rails. Which is a good way to serve up an Ember app?

Answer (score 2):

Ember is a client side framework, you can use whatever server side framework you are comfortable using.

Comment: I'm not asking about server side, I'm asking about which to use to serve up the ember app...

Comment: I'm sorry, those are the same things.  Unless you are referring to apache/webapi/nginx etc, but the answer is still the same, whichever you are more comfortable using.

Comment: No I mean like should I use yeoman/ember-app-kit?